# The ideal generated by an ideal and an element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ and ideal of $R$ and $x \in R.$ I want to consider the ideal generated by the ideal and the element, $(I, x).$ But how do I think of this? Is this ideal basically the set of all elements of the form $r_1e + r_2x$ where $r_i \in R$ and $e \in I$?

Comment: Sure, or the set of elements of the form $e+rx$ for $r\in R$, $e\in I$.

Comment: I mean the ideal generated by two ideals $I$ and $J$ is $I+J=\{ i+j : i\in I, j\in J\}$, and the ideal generated by a single element is $Rx = \{ rx : r\in R\}$, so the ideal generated by an ideal and a single element is $I+Rx = \{i +rx : i\in I, r\in R\}$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that it is the smallest ideal that contains both $I$ and $x$  (also known as "the intersection of all ideals that contain $I$ and $x$").

Comment: @伽罗瓦 It's important to know what jgon's suggestion only works if you are working with commutative rings. If you are working with rings in general, the elements of $(I,x)$ must look like $i+\sum_j r_jxs_j$ where the $r_j$ and $s_j$ are from $R$, and the sum is finite.